# java load order of jars and other files in a folder

Tags: java, jvm, runtime, classpath, classloader

I have a file and a jar in same folder.

```
a.jar
env.properties
```

a.jar also contains env.properties file with different values.

When I use `java -cp path_to_folder/* ClassName` then java is reading the a.jar -> env.properties file content. When I use `java -cp .:path_to_folder/* ClassName` then java is reading env.properties file's content.

Can we determine the load order of files and jars used by java?

Comment: Please reread and clarify your question.  The second paragraph doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ordering. A class path consists of directories or jar files. So a properties file is never a valid class path entry. When you specify a wildcard like `path_to_folder/*`, it will include all jar files in that directory and nothing else. Only when you explicitly include a directory containing the properties file (i.e. the `.` in your second example) in the class path, the file will be a resource.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things going on here: shell pathname expansion (aka "globbing") and then the `java` commands interpretation of the arguments that it sees.

**Example 1:**

```
java -cp path_to_folder/* ClassName
```

The shell turns that into

```
java -cp path_to_folder/a.jar path_to_folder/env.properties  ClassName
```

Then `java` treats the `path_to_folder/env.properties` *as if* it was the class name, and fails.

**Example 2:**

```
java -cp .:path_to_folder/* ClassName
```

This one is a bit more tricky.  The problem is that the shell tries to expand `.:path_to_folder/*` by interpreting `.:path_to_folder/` as the name of a directory.  (It doesn't know that it represents a colon-separated path.)  That expansion fails, and what java sees is this:

```
java -cp .:path_to_folder/* ClassName
```

But `java` interprets a wildcard in the classpath as matching *only* JAR files.  See [Setting the Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html#A1100762)

So the above is equivalent to this:

```
java -cp .:path_to_folder/a.jar ClassName
```

and the properties file is not on the effective classpath.

**Solution:**

If you want both the JAR and properties file on the classpath, you need to do this:

```
java -cp .:path_to_folder/a.jar:path_to_folder ClassName
```

Now both the JAR file and the folder containing the properties file are on the effective classpath, and the application will be able to read the properties file as a resource using the resource path `/env.properties`.  (It should also read the JAR file as a resource as `/a.jar`.)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but may solve your task:

You could try to read the properties in two steps:

1. Read your jar-internal env.properties as you do already from classpath.
2. Read your jar-external env.properties (which you should place then outside your classpath) via filesystem access:

   `Properties properties = new Properties();`

   `properties.load(new FileInputStream(new File("./env.properties")));`

And then decide (dependent of which is available) which properties to use.

Answer (score 0):

> java -cp path_to_folder/* ClassName

Yes, because this means the 'raw' env file (the one not in the jar) **is not even on the classpath**. The above line of code doesn't work at all except on windows (it should be put on quotes on all other platforms): That star needs to arrive unmolested by the shell as an argument straight to the java executable, and this means: **all jars in this directory**. Not the directory *itself*.

Hence, yes, of course, this means only the env file in the jar is on the classpath. By definition.

> java -cp .:path_to_folder/* ClassName

Yes, now both are on the classpath. I *think* it then goes in order; `./env.properties` works, so that wins, as `.` is the first entry in the classpath. Yeah, `path_to_folder/foo.jar!/env.properties` would also work, but classpath scanning stops on a hit, unless you are using a ClassLoader's `findResources` option (which would find both of them).